# Is my code for mirror image of a 2D array correct?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public int [][] Mirror(int [][] A1){ 
    int [][] A2 = new int [A1.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < A1.length; i++) {
        for(int j = A1[i].length-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            A2[i][j] = A1[i][j];
        }
    }
    return A2;
}
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this code. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "*I am not sure what is wrong with this code.*" Why do you think it's wrong? Did you try it and not get the desired results? What sample input and output did you examine?

Answer (score 2):

`A2[i][j] = A1[i][j]` assigns the exact same values of the input array to the same indices in the output array, so the output array would be identical to the input array.

It should be

```
A2[i][j] = A1[i][A1[i].length-1-j];
```

This way, for example, the last column of each row in the input array becomes the first column in the output array.